# How to manually set upstream proxy for fiddler core?

Tags: c#, fiddler, fiddlercore

I'd like to be able to redirect http requests from fiddler code through upstream proxys, which I want to be able to specify at runtime.

I've looked through `FiddlerApplication` functions, and I don't see anything that might fit, as well as I haven't found anything matching in the documentation (except that you might specify a startup flag to use system's proxy as upstream proxy).

What is the best way to specify/change fiddler core proxy at runtime?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to send each request to a proxy, and that proxy isn't the system's default: Before each request is sent, specify the **X-OverrideGateway** flag on the Session. Inside your BeforeRequest handler, add the following line:

```
oSession["X-OverrideGateway"] = "someProxy:1234";
```

-Eric

Comment: in this case, how do I set proxy user name and password?

Comment: Fiddler does not (generally) authenticate to proxies automatically on your behalf; instead, the core application can do so. If the proxies are using HTTP BASIC authentication, you can add your own Proxy-Authorization header directly.

Comment: If you did want Fiddler to respond to the auth proxy, see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fiddler/archive/2011/09/04/fiddler-http-401-authentication-workaround-to-support-channel-binding-tokens-removing-endless-prompts.aspx for the procedure.

Comment: Hello I added that but I'm getting this error `[Fiddler] The connection to 'blahblah.com' failed.  <br />System.IO.InvalidDataException SOCKS gateway failed: Gateway returned error 0x5b-&#39;request rejected or failed&#39;` I added `oSession["X-OverrideGateway"] = "socks=192.168.1.12:2040";` It's a socks5 proxy.

Answer (score 2):

As EricLaw have said in his answer that you have to specify X-OverrideGateway flag on the Session, although if you want to do a basic HTTP authentication to the upstream proxy, you can set the credentials by adding the Proxy-Authorization header to the session inside your BeforeRequest handler like that

```
string userCredentials = string.Format("{0}:{1}", "user", "password");
string base64UserCredentials = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(userCredentials));
oSession.RequestHeaders["Proxy-Authorization"] = "Basic " + base64UserCredentials;
```

Here's a list of the HTTP header fields
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields