# How to check if browser is open

Tags: c#, google-chrome, firefox, browser

How to check if a browser is open? I know i can check a process but sometimes process is running but on the computer browser is still launching. I need it only for 2 browsers, Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: So how make it in JavaScript and implement in my program?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below code gets the file names of all running process. if firefox.exe exist in the return hashset list it means firefox is running.

```
var RunningProcessPaths = ProcessFileNameFinderClass.GetAllRunningProcessFilePaths();

if (RunningProcessPaths.Contains("firefox.exe"))
{
    //firefox is running
    Debug.WriteLine("firefox is running");
}

if (RunningProcessPaths.Contains("chrome.exe"))
{
    //Google Chrome is running
    Debug.WriteLine("chrome is running");
}
```

Helper Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class ProcessFileNameFinderClass
{
    public static HashSet<string> GetAllRunningProcessFilePaths()
    {
        var allProcesses = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses();
        HashSet<string> ProcessExeNames = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        foreach (Process p in allProcesses)
        {
            string processExePath = GetProcessExecutablePath(p);
            ProcessExeNames.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(processExePath));
        }
        return ProcessExeNames;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Get executable path of running process
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Process"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string GetProcessExecutablePath(Process Process)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6)
            {
                return GetExecutablePathAboveXP(Process.Id);// this gets the process file name without running as administrator 
            }
            return Process.MainModule.FileName;// Vista and later this requires running as administrator.
        }
        catch
        {
            return "";
        }
    }

    public static string GetExecutablePathAboveXP(int ProcessId)
    {
        int MAX_PATH = 260;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(MAX_PATH + 1);
        IntPtr hprocess = OpenProcess(ProcessAccessFlags.PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, false, ProcessId);
        if (hprocess != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            try
            {
                int size = sb.Capacity;
                if (QueryFullProcessImageName(hprocess, 0, sb, ref size))
                {
                    return sb.ToString();
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                CloseHandle(hprocess);
            }
        }
        return "";
    }

    [Flags()]
    private enum ProcessAccessFlags : uint
    {
        PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS = 0x1f0fff,
        PROCESS_TERMINATE = 0x1,
        PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD = 0x2,
        PROCESS_VM_OPERATION = 0x8,
        PROCESS_VM_READ = 0x10,
        PROCESS_VM_WRITE = 0x20,
        PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE = 0x40,
        PROCESS_SET_INFORMATION = 0x200,
        PROCESS_SET_QUOTA = 0x100,
        PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION = 0x400,
        PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION = 0x1000,
        SYNCHRONIZE = 0x100000,
        PROCESS_CREATE_PROCESS = 0x80,
        PROCESS_SUSPEND_RESUME = 0x800
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern bool QueryFullProcessImageName(IntPtr hProcess, uint dwFlags, [Out(), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] StringBuilder lpExeName, ref int lpdwSize);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(ProcessAccessFlags dwDesiredAccess, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool bInheritHandle, int dwProcessId);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hHandle);
}
```